# Elasticsearch search template not working with terms query

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have an index with a long field and i am just trying to use search template to use terms query but it throws exception.

```
"pid": {
         "type": "long"
       }
```

Search Template:
PUT  /_search/template/article_query_template

```
{
 "template": {
 "query": {
 "terms": {
 "pid": "{{articleId}}"
 }
}
}
 }
```

Search Query :

POST test2*/_search

```
{
  "query": {
          "template": {
              "id": "article_query_template", 
              "params" : {
                  "articleId" : ["1"]
              }
          }
      }
}
```

Exception : reason": "[terms] query does not support [pid]".

Its working without template. How to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure you need `query` two times in your template definition.

Comment: @Val i have removed single query and tried testing but again getting same exception.

Comment: Which version of ES are you using?

Comment: @val ES 2.4.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Create your template like :

```
{
"source": {
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "message": "{{query_string}}"
        }
    }
}
}
```

and pass params like :

```
{
"id": "<templateName>", 
"params": {
    "query_string": "search for these words"
}}
```

More details are available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html).